# Power BI: extract text in a certain pattern

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I'm fairly new to using Power BI, and tried searching to see if this has been answered previously, but couldn't find anything that matched exactly what I'm looking for.

I have a column of data that includes project names and an ID number in parentheses. Example:
John's Project (12345)

I'm trying to extract just the ID number, but the issue I'm running into is that some rows have other numbers outside the parentheses so I can't rely on just pulling out any numeric characters, and some rows may have multiple sets of parentheses so I can't rely on just selecting text between two delimiters.

Sample data:

| ProjectTitle |
| --- |
| John's Project (12345) |
| Website redesign 2021 (98765) |
| New Accounting System (NAS) (45645) |
| Customer Service Contact Form (32198) (On Hold) |

In each case, I want to copy the five-digit number into a separate column. Is there an easy way to do this when the text could sometimes have other numbers and/or other text inside of parentheses, which could come before or after the parentheses I'm interested in?

Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 0):

What about

```
=MID([ProjectTitle], SEARCH("(?????)", [ProjectTitle]) + 1, 5)
```

This searches for the position of five characters surrounded by parentheses, and then extracts five characters from the next position (i. e. ignoring the opening parenthesis)-

Comment: I tried this, but it's giving me an error message: "Expression.Error: The import MID matches no exports. Did you miss a module reference?"

Comment: @bober8255 For me, my formula works in the newest PowerBI Desktop version 2.92.706.0 64-bit (April 2021). A similar error  message was reported at https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Expression-Error-The-import-R-Execute-matches-no-exports-Did-you/td-p/412043, and got resolved by someone by updating PowerBI to a newer version, someone else by changing the data type of the column, and someone third just by refreshing the preview.  Maybe these approaches are worth trying.